# How to validate Laravel 4 form (html) with js framework

Tags: laravel-4, webforms, javascript, javascript-framework

I am developed a laravel web application with forms. My client is not satisfied with laravel form validation because its validating from server side and reload the page, its taking more time. I want to validate form from client side.. which js framework is most suitable for laravel 4. I need the laravel form validation methords like min,max,numeric,alphanumeric,alpha. With custom validation error messages.

Also please give the best tutorial link for your suggestion. ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making an AJAX call to the backend, making use of Laravel's form validators, as the user tabs to the next input field? That way the form is validated prior to submit.

Answer (score 0):

I manage the validation from you can use any framework and any CMS try it.

p{color:red;}

```
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
     (function($,W,D)
    {
        var JQUERY4U = {};

        JQUERY4U.UTIL =
        {
            setupFormValidation: function()
            {
                //form validation rules
                $("#register-form").validate({
                    rules: {

                        roll: {required : true, minlength : 2,digits: true},
                        lastname: {required : true},
                        agree: "required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        roll: {required :"<p>Please enter roll</p>", minlength : "<p>Must be at least 2 characters</p>",digits :"<p>Please enter integer Numper Only</p>"   },
                        lastname: {required :"<p>Please enter lastname</p>" },
                        agree: "Please accept our policy"
                    }               
                });
            }       
        }

        //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
        $(D).ready(function($) {
            JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();

        });

    })(jQuery, window, document);
    </script>
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>classname/functionname/" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate" />
    <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="roll" value="">
    <input class="form-control"  type="text" name="lastname" value="">
</form>
```